# Developing for iOS on Linux

Tags: ios, iphone, linux

I am looking for an engine or library to develop a game for iOS on Linux.

High level, low level, GUI, no GUI, does not matter too much. I am really looking for anything.

I'm not actually talking about deploying to iOS from Linux or anything like. I just want to do the bulk of the work on Linux, with minimal changes required to run it on iOS.

Edit: YES, I do have access to a Mac, but it is limited. So I want to be able to work on the project on my regular Ubuntu box.

Also, I am in the paid developer program, so I can deploy to iOS devices from the Mac.

Comment: MonoDroid should be getting Linux support at some point - if you write your game with MonoGame you can cross-compile it with very little effort. At the end of the day I think you do need a Mac.

Comment: Is a virtual machine an option?

Comment: @stephelton I now have full time access to a Mac, so this is no longer a problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much screwed - while there are many libraries and frameworks that allow development on Linux, to do any serious testing you'll need a Mac (or Hackintosh, din't say it). Deployment is one problem, but testing on any simulator is another.

Linux also doesn't run Unity, which would be another good solution.

However, you can take a look at one of the many home rolled solutions. In particular, a really low level solution would be using [SDL 1.3+](http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php) -- it has built in support for iOS as a target.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I do have some access to a Mac. See my updated OP.

Comment: You're best sticking to limited access to the Mac. You're going to waste hours getting a non-Mac system running and you won't even be able to test your code on the simulator, which means you won't be able to bug fix. Your whole workflow is going to be a convoluted mess.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your app on a real iOS device and later release it, there is no legal way but to purchase a mac device. but If you are looking for a way to develop an app and test it on emulators, you can try using gnustep. note that can try an app written by gnustep, using a jail broken device.

besides if you don't mind working with C++ there is cocos2d-x you can try.

the last option (which also is illegal) is to use emulated MacOS.

this question is also somehow duplicate on StackOverFlow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Comment: Illegal? Even if your copy of MacOS is original? Are you sure?

Comment: @Lohoris yeah, I'm sure about that. MacOS can only be installed on a mac device. though I've got some friends who deployed their iOS games using emulated MacOS, but Apple strictly forbids such an action.

Comment: And do you know if there is any sentence anywhere which _actually_ confirms the validity of that clause, or it is just another random clause they put into contracts but has never been tested in a tribunal?

Comment: read it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86#Legal_issues_and_Apple_objections

Comment: lol that's really terrible, though not surprising after all

Answer (score 1):

I now have full time use of a Mac, so I no longer need to develop for iOS on a Linux machine.

However, [gameplay](http://gameplay3d.org) (gameplay3d.org), an open source project by Research In Motion (RIM), looks really good. It is primarily a 3D engine, and uses C++. It also has Lua scripting support.

I haven't actually tested gameplay on Linux, but it appears to have full support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Moai](http://getmoai.com/) to develop iOS and Android apps from Windows, Mac, and Linux.

However, you're going to need a Mac in order to deploy or test your app.

Comment: I have looked at Moai in the past, but there is no official support for Linux. And I do have some access to a Mac, see my updated OP.

Answer (score -1):

You can develop a game with flash and build it to iOS using [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html)

However, you're going to need a Mac in order to deploy or test your app.

Comment: Does Adobe Air work on Linux? Also, that last line applies to my answer as well; copied!

Comment: Well.. I'm not sure about compiling with adobe air, but he said he wants to do the bulk of the work on Linux, so he can develop in any ActionScript IDE and even run and test it on the flash player for linux.

Comment: Hey what's with the down vote with no comment or explanation? Not cool...